# @font-face issue when weights are set

Tags: css, html, frontend

If I use @font-face and set font-weight: 900; for example.

And inside my css use it as font-family: "custom-font", Arial; and font-weight: 100;

I expect browser to show Arial, since custom-font is only 900. But this is not what happens, browser loads custom-font for all weights.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The font delegation means that if `custom-font` is not installed (regardless of the specified weight) on the user's machine, it will fall back to Arial. Just because the `custom-font` does not exist in a weight of 900 does not mean the browser will delegate to Arial.

Comment: Thanks, that seems counterintuitive for me. Because I consider font to be sum of weight/style. Is there more I can read about this somewhere?